# How to Insert Text File Line by Line into Web SQL Database

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

So I'm trying to get this to work. I have a text file that I'm using so that the user can backup some of his or her data from a web sql database, which is working ok. However, I need it so that they can upload the text file back into the site and it will insert the content of that file back into the web sql database. Here's some of my code so far:

window.onload = function() {
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');

```
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function () {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var textType = /text.*/;

        if (file.type.match(textType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(progressEvent) {
                var mydata = reader.result.split('\n');

      for(var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
      mydb.transaction(function (u) {
        u.executeSql("INSERT INTO link_table (make, model) VALUES (?, ?)", [mydata, mydata]);
        outputCars();
      });
    }
            };
    reader.readAsText(file);
        }
    });
```

};

This code inserts the whole text file into one table cell of the database. So, if I had this text file:

www.google.com 
www.bing.com

it puts both url's in one cell of the column. I'd like it to be so that it reads the text file line by line and inserts each line into a new column of the database. Any help would be appreciated, and the only requirement is that it has to be done all client side. So no PHP or anything like that. Thanks!

Comment: Guessing you should be using mydata[i] inside your loop somewhere...

Comment: +seth flowers I tried that, and it does create columns for the information, only issue is that it inserts UNDEFINED in each of the cells instead of the text data.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code here:

```
 reader.onload = function(progressEvent) {

 var lines = reader.result.split('\n');
 for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
  alert(lines[line]);
 }
 };
```